# JVM crashes with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), points to jvm.dll

Tags: java, dll, jvm, access-violation, sumo

The JVM running my simulation client (for SUMO, using TraCI as libtraci) keeps crashing.
This is the command line message:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffd7e94b97c, pid=33996, tid=26012

JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.5+8 (17.0.5+8) (build 17.0.5+8)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.5+8 (17.0.5+8, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
Problematic frame:
V  \[jvm.dll+0x80b97c\]

No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\\Projekte\\Bachelorarbeit\\Simulationstudie\\Simulacrum\\hs_err_pid33996.log
Compiled method (c1)  921857 2548       3       org.eclipse.sumo.libtraci.TraCINextStopData::getLane (9 bytes)
total in heap  \[0x0000016a8841b810,0x0000016a8841bb58\] = 840
relocation     \[0x0000016a8841b968,0x0000016a8841b9a0\] = 56
main code      \[0x0000016a8841b9a0,0x0000016a8841baa0\] = 256
stub code      \[0x0000016a8841baa0,0x0000016a8841bae8\] = 72
oops           \[0x0000016a8841bae8,0x0000016a8841baf0\] = 8
metadata       \[0x0000016a8841baf0,0x0000016a8841baf8\] = 8
scopes data    \[0x0000016a8841baf8,0x0000016a8841bb10\] = 24
scopes pcs     \[0x0000016a8841bb10,0x0000016a8841bb50\] = 64
dependencies   \[0x0000016a8841bb50,0x0000016a8841bb58\] = 8

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The same exception access violation keeps occuring at different times during runs of my simulation. The problematic frame has so far always stated 'jvm.dll' and the compiled method is also consistently libtraci.TraCINextStopData::getLane.

I have so far tried a different JVM version and a different libtraci version with the same results and am now a little dumbstruck on what to try next.

[EDIT: I'm happy to provide the relevant log file 'hs_err_pid33996.log', but am a bit unsure of how to best include it here. Should I post the content of the entire (very long) file?]

Comment: You could upload the logs and possibly also the scenario itself to some public space and add  a link here. Or you just send your report with attachments to the sumo mailing list, see https://www.eclipse.org/sumo/contact/